# Detecting duplicate record on on Imported data

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, csv

I am trying to import data from the csv file and I have to check if there are duplicate rows which has the same column values. I am having trouble coding it so I hope all of you may help me. Thanks

Oh my csv file contains 9 columns

```
public class Reporting_TestClassTest {
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
public String csvAsString{get;set;}
public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
public List<CsvData> csv{get;set;}

public class CsvData {
    public Date dates{get;set;}
    public String dept{get;set;}
    public String devName{get;set;}
    public String classAdd{get;set;}
    public String violation{get;set;}
    public String section{get;set;}
    public Integer pHit1{get;set;}
    public Integer pHit2{get;set;}
    public Integer pHit3{get;set;}
    public Integer pHit4{get;set;}
    public Integer lineNum{get;set;}
    public String comments{get;set;}

     public CsvData(Date dates, String dept, String devName, String classAdd, String violation, String section,
                    Integer pHit1, Integer pHit2, Integer pHit3, Integer pHit4, Integer lineNum, String comments){

        this.dates = dates;
        this.dept = dept;
        this.devName = devName;
        this.classAdd = classAdd;
        this.violation = violation;
        this.section = section;
        this.pHit1 = pHit1;
        this.pHit2 = pHit2;
        this.pHit3 = pHit3;
        this.pHit4 = pHit4;
        this.lineNum = lineNum;
        this.comments = comments;

    }
}

public Reporting_TestClassTest(){
    csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    csv = new List<CsvData>();
}
public void importCSVFile(){
    try{
        csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
        csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');
        Set<CsvData> csvCheckDupli = new Set<CsvData>();
        List<CsvData> csvList = new List<CsvData>();
        CsvData cs;


        for(Integer i = 1; i < csvFileLines.size(); i++){
            String[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');

            String pHit = csvRecordData[6];
            Integer pHit1 = 0;
            Integer pHit2 = 0;
            Integer pHit3 = 0;
            Integer pHit4 = 0;

                if(pHit == 'P1'){
                    pHit1++;
                }else if(pHit == 'P2'){
                    pHit2++;
                }
                else if(pHit == 'P3'){
                    pHit3++;
                }else if(pHit == 'P4'){
                    pHit4++;
                }

            cs = new CsvData(Date.valueOf(csvRecordData[0]), csvRecordData[1], csvRecordData[2], csvRecordData[3], csvRecordData[4], csvRecordData[5], pHit1, pHit2,pHit3,pHit4
                                        ,Integer.valueOf(csvRecordData[7]), csvRecordData[8]);

            if(csvCheckDupli.contains(cs)){
                System.debug('Duplicate Detected');  
            }else{
                csv.add(cs); 
                csvCheckDupli.add(cs);
            }

        }   
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'An error has occured while importing data Please make sure input file is correct');
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Does your CSV file contain any kind of key? Are you also updating existing records? If so using external Id fields and an upsert operation would prevent duplicates, though it would update records with the same key. Another option to look at would be [using matching rules, and duplicate rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=matching_rules_overview.htm&type=0) - this way you can manage any duplicates and also warn the user of potential duplicates. This helps prevent duplicates both in the standard SalesForce.com UI, dataloader and in your case Apex classes.